# PHP - I need help, how can I access a specific data in stdClass Object?

Tags: php, soap, stdclass

```
stdClass Object ( 
 [Met01InResult] => {
 "Matricula":"UXX00000001",
 "NoEmpleado":"",
 "Nombre":"pruebas.universidad",
 "Estatus":"10",
 "Mensaje":"Operación exitosa.",
 "Iddireccion":0,
 "Direccion":"ALUMNADO",
 "IdPuesto":0,
 "Puesto":"ALUMNO",
 "Esprofesor":false} 
)
```

Comment: Hello, you should use improved markup to display your code. because it's unreadable here.
To access attrbiute in stdClass use "->" example : `$object->Met01InResult`

Comment: That appears to be a JSON *inside* a stdClass object, so you'll probably need to `json_decode()` `$object->Met01InResult` before you can really do anything with it.

Comment: thanks for your help.

Comment: Please add what you have tried. This way others will also see what will work and what will not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to access the attribute inside your object you have to use `$object->Met01InResult` (replace object by your variables containing this object.
Moreover the key `Met01InResult` contains a JSON string so you've to transform it to an array (by example) using [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php).

To resume, i provide this example.

```
// Your Object vairable ($object)
$result = json_decode($object->Met01InResult, true); //the true parameter ensure $result   to be an assoc' array
//Result contains an array with the json data within Met01InResult.
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for your help.